# Evaluate the image of a function

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am given a function:
$f: \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}, \space\space f(x,y)=(x-y^2)(y-x^2)$.

I have to evaluate the image $f(A)$ of a set $A=\mathbb{R}^+\times \mathbb{R}^+$.

I tried to muplitply the brackets and what I got was: 
$f(x, y)=-x^3-y^3+x^2y^2+xy$ 
When I looked for some particular points, hoping to find a pattern, I got nothing: 
$f(2,3)=(2-9)(3-4)=7$
$f(2,4)=(2-16)(4-4)=0$
$f(1,10)=(1-100)(10-1)=-891$
The only thing that comes to my mind is the answer $f(A)=\mathbb{R}$

How do I find the image? Generally, how to solve this type of problem?

Comment: Can you please include your try inside your question

Comment: What kind of class is this for? I'm asking because what's used in the answer may vary depending on what you know about topology and/or calculus.

Comment: I would advice to find $f(\partial A)$ first, which means $f(\{0\}\times\mathbb{R})\cup f(\mathbb{R}\times\{0\})$. It is a good way to guess the answer. Then, depending on the answer to @David's question, you may use the concept of connectedness, or not, if you are not familiar with it.

Comment: This is for the 'Elements of Logic and Set Theory' class. It doesn't contain any topological topics.

Comment: You get all values $\geq 0$ by taking $x = y$, and all values $\leq 0$ by taking $y = 1$. For the second statement, the only proof I see at the moment uses the intermediate value theorem. If you want a proof without that, it might take more work.

Answer (score 0):

$f(x,y)=(x-y^{2})(y-x^{2})=x^{2}y^{2}-x^{3}-y^{3}+xy$

For $x,y,t \in \mathbb{R}^{+}$,

$f(x,0^{+})=-x^{3} \in (-\infty,0)$,

$f(0^{+},y)=-y^{3} \in (-\infty,0)$,

$f(t,t)=t^{4}-2t^{3}+t^{2}=t^{2}(t-1)^{2} \in [0,\infty)$

$\therefore f[A]= \mathbb{R}$

Comment: $f(A)\in\mathbb{R}$ has no meaning. More importantly, the point is not to prove that $f(A)\subset \mathbb{R}$, which is trivial, but $\mathbb{R}\subset f(A)$, for which you roughly give the ideas of the proofs, but it should be done more rigorously

Comment: Corrected, many thx.